Trying to add Password Recovery in my laravel project but encountered an error
So im trying to follow this youtube tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gdQHj-K9f94&t=617s
It's a laravel project walkthrough where he adds password recovery, i followed this video, saw he used mailtrap, didn't mind that, idk what mailtrap is i just wanted to test if it worked. After following his tutorial i got this error in my local host
Connection could not be established with host "mailpit:1025": stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mailpit failed: No such host is known.
and it highlighted this code
    $status = Password::sendResetLink(

Is the error only due to me running it in a local environment? Will this work when i upload the site to hostinger (my hosting site)?
So I followed only this mentioned video, i get its a multi part but i only needed this function, what i expected to happen was it would email my gmail somehow and the reset link would work. It didn't

This is likely due to some configuration issues. If you're following a tutorial where it sends to MailTrap, but you don't use that, then you can't expect the code to work for you... You can signup for a Mailtrap account, I used one a while back to test emails from my local install of a Laravel project. Or, you can look into the documentation for Laravel's mail logic: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/mail and implement the logic you need. "what i expected to happen was it would email my gmail somehow" - Given the configuration in that tutorial, that expectation is unrealistic...

@TimLewis thanks for the quick response, ill look into this documentation, he didnt use any mailtrap specific code in the tutorial, but i guess laravel just defaults to mailtrap in that case. Also a follow up question, what would happen if i pushed this in my deployed site? Cant risk testing since its used by others

"i guess laravel just defaults to mailtrap" - not clear why you say this, the error you are seeing says Laravel is trying to use Mailpit. MailTrap is another option, and there are others, edit your configuration to choose.  "he didnt use any mailtrap specific code" - once you've configured a "mailer", Laravel will use it, there is no need to do anything more.  The easiest to get started is the "log" driver, which just writes mails to a logfile on your local disk (that is the default).

"he didnt use any mailtrap specific code in the tutorial" - I haven't watched this tutorial, but that's kinda the point; you set configuration and choose your Mailer (in this case MailTrap), and Laravel does the rest. "what would happen if i pushed this in my deployed site" - You'd get the same error on your site as you do locally, unless you've configured your site to use MailTrap ‍♂️

You guys are correct, I just checked the .env file, my partner on this project did some mailpit testing and didn't tell me, its fixed now and is successfully sending emails
